# 2D Python game map update after movement

Tags: python

I am currently working on 2D game which is using text as a textures in python. The main idea for this game is to collect the treasure and try to escape the ghost aka monster. After lots of struggle I finally added movement system for player and monster. Everything is working like it should as coordinates are changing properly (function info() will show them), however my map does not update and i have no idea how can i update it.

Map is 12x12

```
#map generation

map_width = 12
map_height = 12
player_view = 1
map = [([1] * map_width)] + ([([1] + ([0] * (map_width - 2)) + [1]) for _ in range(map_height - 2)]) + [([1] * map_width)]
def print_map():
  for row in map:
    print(*row, sep='\t')
    print("\n")
```

Generation of “objects” like player, monster and treasure. During the player generation there will be generation of the vision along.

```
#player generation + vision
    
  player = {
      "x_p":random.randint(1,map_width  - 2),
      "y_p":random.randint(1,map_height - 2),
      
  }
  map[player["y_p"]][player["x_p"]] = ‘’
  for i,row in enumerate(map[player["y_p"]- player_view :player["y_p"]+1 + player_view]):
    for j,element in enumerate(row[player["x_p"]- player_view :player["x_p"]+1 + player_view]):
      if (element == 0):
        map[player["y_p"] - player_view + i][player["x_p"] - player_view +j]=''

#monster generation

  monster = {
      'y_m':random.randint(1, map_width - 2),
  }
  possible_x = []
  for i,e in enumerate(map[monster['y_m']]):
    if e == 0:
      possible_x.append(i)
  monster['x_m'] = random.choice(possible_x)
  map[monster["y_m"]][monster["x_m"]]=''

#treasure generation

  treasure = {
      'y_t':random.randint(1, map_width - 2),
  }
  possible_x = []
  for i,e in enumerate(map[treasure['y_t']]):
    if e == 0:
      possible_x.append(i)
  treasure['x_t'] = random.choice(possible_x)
  map[treasure["y_t"]][treasure["x_t"]]=''
```

All of the functions which are used in program

```
#printing info about characters, map dimensions and icons used

def info():
    print('\n')
    #print_map()
    #print('\n')
    print('Map dimentions are',map_width, 'x', map_height, '(including walls!)\n')
    print('Player -',player, 'Icon used:',player_character, '\n')
    print('Monster -',monster, 'Icon used: .\n')
    print('Treasure -',treasure, 'Icon used: .\n')
    print('Player vision value is', player_view,', and is represented with icon: .\n')
    print('Other icons used, 0 as empty area and 1 as walls. \n')

#generating number 1 or -1 randomly in order to select direction of monster movement

def monster_random_values():
  exclude = [0]
  movement_value = random.randint(-1,1)
  return my_custom_random() if movement_value in exclude else movement_value
```

And finally the movement system for player and monster

```
loop = True
while loop:

    # movment system
    movment_choice = input('Please select your movment choice - [W,A,S,D]\nIf you want to exit press [Q]\n')
    if movment_choice == 'W' or movment_choice == 'w':
        print_map()
        player['y_p'] = (player['y_p'] + 1)
        #print(map[player['y_p']])
        info()
    elif movment_choice == 'A' or movment_choice == 'a':
        player['x_p'] = (player['x_p'] - 1)
        #print(map[player['x_p']])
        info()
    elif movment_choice == 'S' or movment_choice == 's':
        player['y_p'] = (player['y_p'] - 1)
        #print(map[player['y_p']])
        info()
    elif movment_choice == 'D' or movment_choice == 'd':
        player['x_p'] = (player['x_p'] + 1)
        #print(player['x_p'])
        info()
    elif movment_choice == 'Q':
      print('Thank you for playing the game!\n See you soon!')
      loop = False
    else:
        print('ERROR! Please select one of the options in the question')

    #monster movment
    possible_movment = random.randint(1, 3)
    if possible_movment == 1:
      monster['y_m'] = (monster['y_m'] + monster_random_values())
      monster['x_m'] = (monster['x_m'] + monster_random_values())
    elif possible_movment == 2:
      monster['y_m'] = (monster['y_m'] + monster_random_values())
    elif possible_movment == 3:
      monster['x_m'] = (monster['x_m'] + monster_random_values())
      info()
```

I hope that it is clear. If it will not work properly i will sent a full version of a code.

Thank you for help!

Comment: First, `map` is a python builtin function so I'd avoid using it as a variable name. To generate a simple map like this I'd use `set` objects. These allow you to make quick operations and build the game map with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, `map` is a python builtin. It is advised not to use it as a variable name.

Second, I'd make the map creation a function and use the object returned by it.

Here's a sample code using `set` and procedural generation of the game map. Using operations of sets we will keep them from overlapping objects in the map. I will be using a `tuple` for positions.

```
import random
BORDER = '1'

def create_map(map_width, map_height, num_treasures=1):
    locations = set((i, j) for i in range(map_height) for j in range(map_width))  # All available board coordinates
    player = (random.randint(1, map_width - 2), random.randint(1, map_height - 2))  # Player position
    locations = locations.difference({player})  # Remove player position from available positions
    border = ({(0, i) for i in range(map_width)}.union({(map_height - 1, i) for i in range(map_width)})).union(
        {(i, 0) for i in range(map_height)}.union({(i, map_height - 1) for i in range(map_height)}))  # All borders
    locations = locations.difference(border)  # Remove border from available locations
    vision = {(player[0] + dx, player[1] + dy) for dx in [-1, 0, 1] for dy in [-1, 0, 1]}.intersection(
        locations)  # 3 x 3 vision box. Player is not used since its location is not available in locations
    monster = random.choice(list(locations))  # Monster location selected randomly from available locations
    locations = locations.difference({monster})  # Remove monster from available locations
    treasures = set([])  # Do the same thing as monster with treasures in a loop
    for i in range(num_treasures):
        treasure = random.choice(list(locations))
        treasures.add(treasure)
        locations.remove(treasure)
    my_map = list(list([0] * map_width) for _ in range(map_height))  # Empty map
    my_map[player[0]][player[1]] = ''  # Set player
    my_map[monster[0]][monster[1]] = ''  # Set monster
    for x, y in border:  # Set border
        my_map[x][y] = BORDER
    for x, y in vision:  # Set vision
        my_map[x][y] = ''
    for x, y in treasures:  # Set treasures
        my_map[x][y] = ''
    return my_map, player, monster, treasures
```

Lastly, I don't see any updates happening in the game `while` loop. You can do this using another function.

```
def move(my_map, player, player_move):
    # Legal move inputs
    if player_move in ['a', 'A']:  
        player_move = (0, -1)
        vision_remove = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
    elif player_move in ['w', 'W']:
        player_move = (-1, 0)
        vision_remove = [(1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
    elif player_move in ['d', 'D']:
        player_move = (0, 1)
        vision_remove = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
    elif player_move in ['s', 'S']:
        player_move = (1, 0)
        vision_remove = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)]
    else:
        return False, my_map, player
    neighbors = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
    # New position
    x = player[0] + player_move[0]
    y = player[1] + player_move[1]
    if my_map[x][y] != BORDER:  # Can't move into borders
        my_map[player[0]][player[1]] = 0
        my_map[x][y] = ''
        # Update vision while keeping treasure, ghost, border icons
        for dx, dy in vision_remove:  # Remove old vision
            value = my_map[player[0] + dx][player[1] + dy]
            my_map[player[0] + dx][player[1] + dy] = 0 if value == '' else value
        for dx, dy in neighbors:  # Add new vision
            value = my_map[x + dx][y + dy]
            my_map[x + dx][y + dy] = '' if value == 0 else value
        return True, my_map, (x, y)
    return False, my_map, player
```

Some of the helper functions:

```
def to_string(my_map):
    return '\n'.join('\t'.join(str(x) for x in y) for y in my_map)


def print_map(my_map):
    print(to_string(my_map))
```

The move function doesn't detect picking up treasure, walking into ghosts as it is. Those need to be added.

The main loop would look something like this:

```
my_map, player, monster, treasures = create_map(12, 12, 3)
updated = True
while True:
    # movement system
    if updated:
        updated = False
        print_map(my_map)
    movement_choice = input('Please select your movment choice - [W,A,S,D]\nIf you want to exit press [Q]\n')
    if movement_choice in ['q', 'Q']:
        print('Thank you for playing the game!\n See you soon!')
        break
    if movement_choice not in ['w', 'W', 'a', 'A', 's', 'S', 'd', 'D']:
        print('ERROR! Please select one of the options in the question')
    updated, my_map, player = move(my_map, player, movement_choice)
    hit, my_map, monster = move_monster(my_map, monster)
    if hit:
        print('Oh no! The monster got you.')
        print_map(my_map)
        break
```

Comment: I went ahead and added monster movement as well.